# Why does xmlstarlet say there's no 'ends-with' function?

Tags: xpath, xmlstarlet

I'm using [xmlstarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/) to extract `changeSet` nodes from a [liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/) XML changelog where the `viewName` ends with "v".

However, xmlstarlet is complaining that the `ends-with` XPATH function does not exist:

```
$ xmlstarlet sel -N x="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog" -t -m \
"/x:databaseChangeLog/x:changeSet[x:createView[ends-with(@viewName, 'v')]]" \
-c . public.db.changelog.xml

xmlXPathCompOpEval: function ends-with not found
Unregistered function
Stack usage errror
xmlXPathCompiledEval: 3 objects left on the stack.
runtime error: element for-each
Failed to evaluate the 'select' expression.
None of the XPaths matched; to match a node in the default namespace
use '_' as the prefix (see section 5.1 in the manual).
For instance, use /_:node instead of /node
```

The XML looks a bit like this:

```
<databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.1.xsd">
  <changeSet id="1391529990457-3">
    <createView viewName="myviewnamev"><!-- view definition here --></createView>
  </changeSet>
  <changeSet id="1391529990457-4">
    <createView viewName="anotherviewname"><!-- view definition here --></createView>
  </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

I do know that the XPATH expression is otherwise correct, because if I change the selection criteria to `x:createView[@viewName="myviewnamev"]` then it correctly selects only that `changeLog` entry.

How do I get xmlstarlet to correctly use `ends-with`? Or, is there an alternative way to accomplish what I want to do?

Comment: Where do you see the `ends-with` function in the [XPath specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/)?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper right [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-operators/#func-ends-with) but Jens's answer below has clarified that xmlstarlet doesn't support XPath 2.0.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`xmlstarlet` only supports XPath 1.0, which does not offer an `ends-with($string, $token)` function. You need to use `substring`, `string-length` and and string comparison to construct your own using this pattern:

```
substring($string, string-length($string) - string-length($token) + 1) = $token]
```

Applied to your query, it should look like this (I "precomputed" the string length):

```
/x:databaseChangeLog/x:changeSet[x:createView[
  substring(@viewName, string-length(@viewName)) = 'v']
]
```

Alternatively, you might want to look for a more powerful XPath 2.0/XQuery engine.

Comment: Thanks! Since it's a one-off this solution will be great.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ xml sel -t -c //_:changeSet[_:createView[str:split(@viewName,'')[last()]='v']] -n file.xml

$ xml sel -t -c //_:changeSet[_:createView[str:tokenize(@viewName,'')[last()]='v']] -n file.xml

$ xml sel -t -c //_:changeSet[_:createView[substring(@viewName,string-length(@viewName),1)='v']] -n file.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on @jens-erat's answer ...

```
[substring(@viewName, string-length(@viewName)) = 'v']
```

can be made more DRY by putting the predicate on the @viewName attribute:

```
[@viewName[substring(., string-length(.)) = 'v']]
```

resulting in:

```
$ xmlstarlet sel -N x="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog" -t -m \
"/x:databaseChangeLog/x:changeSet[x:createView
   [@viewName[substring(., string-length(.)) = 'v']]
]" -c . public.db.changelog.xml
```