# Xpath "ends-with" does not work

Tags: xpath, ends-with

I am trying to find an input element with dynamic id name always ending with "register". So far I tried this

```
"//input[@id[ends-with(.,'register')]]"
```

and this

```
"//input[ends-with(@id,'register')]"
```

none of these result in an element. What am I doing wrong? At the same time this works:

```
"//input[@id[contains(.,'register')]]"
```

Here's the part of source:

```
<td class="input">
<input id="m.f0.menu.f2.volumeTabs.BLOCK_COMMON.tcw.form.register" name="m.f0.menu.f2.volumeTabs.BLOCK_COMMON.tcw.form.register" class="aranea-checkbox" type="checkbox"> </td>
```

Comment: which version of xpath do you use?

Comment: In addition to the XPath version (1.0 does not have `ends-with()`), can you also show us some XML that shows the problem?

Comment: ehm, not sure - how can I check version? I am testing via Google Chrome's console. Which version is Chrome using?

Comment: at least show sample XML that can reproduce the problem. Any chance that value of id attribute has whitespace at the end, so it doesn't precisely ends with 'register'?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does xmlstarlet say there's no 'ends-with' function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21602118/why-does-xmlstarlet-say-theres-no-ends-with-function)

Answer (score 126, accepted):

The `ends-with` function is part of xpath 2.0 but browsers (you indicate you're testing with chrome) generally only support 1.0. So you'll have to implement it yourself with a combination of `string-length`, `substring` and equals

```
substring(@id, string-length(@id) - string-length('register') +1) = 'register'
```

Answer (score 6):

The accepted answer by Ian Roberts uses the `@id attribute` twice in his solution.

In this case I prefer to put the predicate on that `@id` like this:

```
//input[@id[substring(.,string-length(.) - string-length('register') + 1) = 'register']]
```