# Selenium Select - Selecting dropdown option by part of the text

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

The class [Selenium Select](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/Select.html) has 3 methods of different option selection:

1. selectByIndex
2. selectByValue
3. selectByVisibleText

Now, I have a situation where I want to select an option by some text that **partially** appear in one of the options visible text (don't want to expose myself to changes in the WHOLE text).

For example:

```
<option value="0" label="not-intresting">VERY-LONG-TEXT-THAT-I-NEED-TO-SELECT-DOLLAR</option>
```

And i want to select this option only by providing the "DOLLAR", something like:

```
select.selectByPartOfVisibleText("DOLLAR")
```

How would you implement it effectively?

Comment: If only partial text is visible and you can use regex then see this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28817563/python-selenium-select-dropdown-option-with-value-matching-regex

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try a logic like this hope this helps

```
List <WebElements> optionsInnerText= driver.findElements(By.tagName("option"));
for(WebElement text: optionsInnerText){
    String textContent = text.getAttribute("textContent");
    if(textContent.toLowerCase.contains(expectedText.toLowerCase))
           select.selectByPartOfVisibleText(expectedText);
    }
}
```

Comment: This might work if the option had the `text-content` attribute but in the OP's case, it doesn't.

Comment: Inspect the Element and view the DOM Panel you'll find all attributes including textContent

Comment: Thanks, that is something like what I needed. Just instead of text.getAttribute("textContent") part I think element.getText should be used.

Answer (score 8):

My solution is to use xpath to find options that are children of the select. Any xpath method can be used to find the select; in this example I am finding the select by id.

```
List<WebElement> options = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//select[@id = 'selectId')]/option"));

for (WebElement option : options) {
    if (option.getText().contains("DOLLAR")) {
        option.click();
        break;
    }
}
```

After a little more thought I realize the option can be found entirely with xpath:

```
driver.findElements(By.xpath("//select[@id = 'selectId')]/option[contains(text(), 'DOLLAR')]")).click();
```

Comment: Why there is a parenthesis after 'selectId'?

Comment: I used the following code in python. Note that the quotation marks. driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id = 'selectId']/option[contains(text(), '" + myVariable + "')]").click()

Answer (score 3):

Using Java 8 Stream/Lambda:

```
protected void selectOptionByPartText(WebElement elementAttr, String partialText) {
        Select select = new Select(elementAttr);
        select.getOptions().parallelStream().filter(option -> option.getAttribute("textContent").toLowerCase().contains(partialText.toLowerCase()))
                .findFirst().ifPresent(option -> select.selectByVisibleText(option.getAttribute("textContent")));
    }
```

Comment: Works great.  Although if you don't want to filter through every option on the page, and just want to search inner text, you can try: `protected void selectOptionByPartText(WebElement select, String partialText)
  {
  Select s = new Select(select);
  s.getOptions()
   .stream()
   .filter(option -> option.getText().toLowerCase().contains(partialText.toLowerCase()))
   .findFirst()
   .ifPresent(option -> s.selectByValue(option.getAttribute("value")));
  }`

Answer (score 2):

In latest Selenium version 3.x or 4.x, Select class can be used to select an option from dropdown.

For example: There is a flavour dropdown where it require to select a flavour which contain name as `Vanilla`.

```
WebElement flavour = driver.findElement(By.id("attribute178"));
Select select = new Select(flavour);
String expectedFlavourName = "Vanilla";
List<WebElement> allFlavourList = select.getOptions();
for (WebElement option : allFlavourList) {
    String currentFlavourName = option.getText();
    if (currentFlavourName.contains(expectedFlavourName)) {
        select.selectByVisibleText(currentFlavourName);
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Eventually I combined the answers here and that's the result:

```
Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//whatever")));

public void selectByPartOfVisibleText(String value) {
    List<WebElement> optionElements = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("SELECT-SELECTOR")).findElements(By.tagName("option"));

    for (WebElement optionElement: optionElements) {
        if (optionElement.getText().contains(value)) {
            String optionIndex = optionElement.getAttribute("index");
            select.selectByIndex(Integer.parseInt(optionIndex));
            break;
        }
    }

    Thread.sleep(300);
}
```

And in **Scala** (need it eventually in Scala) it looks like:

```
  def selectByPartOfVisibleText(value: String) = {
    val optionElements: util.List[WebElement] = selectElement.findElements(By.tagName("option"))

    breakable {
      optionElements.foreach { elm =>
        if (elm.getText.contains(value)) {
          val optionIndex = elm.getAttribute("index")
          selectByIndex(optionIndex.toInt)
          break
        }
      }
    }
    Thread.sleep(300)
  }
```

Comment: I had an issue that the next action didn't happen because the dropdown closure hasn't rendered fast enough.

Answer (score 0):

Get a list of all the `option` values and then check if the value contains your partial text. Something like this:

```
List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.tagName("option"));
Iterator<WebElement> i = list.iterator();
while(i.hasNext()) {
    WebElement wel = i.next();    
    if(wel.getText().contains("your partial text"))
    {
       //select this option
    }
}
```

Comment: Cool, thanks. I just don't really like working explicitly with Iterators, will do it a bit differently.

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
WebElement element = driver.findEle(By.xpath(loc));
            Select select = new Select(element);
            for(int i=1;i<=select.getOptions().size();i++)
            {
                if(select.getOptions().get(i-1).getText().contains(containsTxt))
                {
                    select.selectByIndex(i-1);
                    break;
                }
                if(i==select.getOptions().size())
                {   
                    //"Fail"
                }
            }
```

Answer (score -1):

This is what I used to solve the issue in python.

I used this option, so it selects the text that uses the word `DOLLAR` instead of typing the whole word as the value.

```
Select(driver.find_element_by_name(ELEMENT)).select_by_value("DOLLAR")
```

instead of

```
Select(driver.find_element_by_name(ELEMENT)).select_by_visible_text(text)
```