# How to select option from dropdown with partial text

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automation

id of drop down = "rw_520631"
Value which I want to select from drop down is = "Automation RW (0/6)"

Now here "Automation RW" is static but "(0/6)" can change.
How can I select this using selenium webdriver in JAVA

Comment: Please add your code the relevant html

Answer (score 0):

This question was answered here - [Selenium Select - Selecting dropdown option by part of the text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29772075/selenium-select-selecting-dropdown-option-by-part-of-the-text)

Below is the snippet of the answer:

```
List <WebElements> optionsInnerText= driver.findElements(By.tagName("option"));

 for(WebElement text: optionsInnerText){

String textContent = text.getAttribute("textContent");

if(textContent.toLowerCase.contains(expectedText.toLowerCase))

       select.selectByPartOfVisibleText(expectedText);
}
```