# how to select item in dropdown list with start matching string using selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to fill a form using selenium where a postcode is entered then a dropdown appears with all the addresses in that postcode appear. I'm taking the data from a spreadsheet. when i split the address to take [0] the house name or number, i want to use this to select from the dropdown the correct address. The dropdown lists the full address, i cannot search for the whole address as the ones in my spreadsheet may differ slightly i.e town may be missing.

How would i select by just matching the house name number?

```
HNUM = sheet['B1']
HNUM = HNUM.value
HNUM = HNUM.split()
HNUM = HNUM[0]

dropdown = browser.find_element_by_id('confirmAddressLookup')
housenumElem = Select(dropdown)
housenumElem.select_by_value(HNUM)
```

The above code is not working i figure **i need to somehow partially match** or extract the addresses, split them, then loop through until a match?
from the websites code:

Select your address

THE LONG MILL, ROCHDALE ROAD, GREETLAND, HALIFAX, WEST YORKSHIRE HX4 8AL


16 ROCHDALE ROAD, GREETLAND, HALIFAX, WEST YORKSHIRE HX4 8AL


24 ROCHDALE ROAD, GREETLAND, HALIFAX, WEST YORKSHIRE HX4 8AL


26 ROCHDALE ROAD, GREETLAND, HALIFAX, WEST YORKSHIRE HX4 8AL


59 ROCHDALE ROAD, GREETLAND, HALIFAX, WEST YORKSHIRE HX4 8AL


65 ROCHDALE ROAD, GREETLAND, HALIFAX, WEST YORKSHIRE HX4 8AL


69 ROCHDALE ROAD, GREETLAND, HALIFAX, WEST YORKSHIRE HX4 8AL


77 ROCHDALE ROAD, GREETLAND, HALIFAX, WEST YORKSHIRE HX4 8AL


83 ROCHDALE ROAD, GREETLAND, HALIFAX, WEST YORKSHIRE HX4 8AL

I think i need to loop through each value and search for the house number '24' in this example but i do not know how to implement it.

Comment: So you said "I'm taking the data from a spreadsheet", but also the selenium? Are you comparing the spreadsheet to what you are looking at in the browser? Also, it would be helpful if you explained what is happening rather than the code "is not working"

Comment: Please check link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29772075/selenium-select-selecting-dropdown-option-by-part-of-the-text

Comment: can you post your html code here? you will have to find the drop down list element using the partial string obtained from excel cell.

Comment: @pjmaracs yes I am taking the address from a spreadsheet, so firstly i have .split the address in order to first enter the postcode into the relevant box, this then brings up a dropdown list containing all of the addresses within that postcode. For example the address  from the postcode i want is: 
24 ROCHDALE ROAD, GREETLAND, HALIFAX, WEST YORKSHIRE HX4 8AL

I cannot search for the full address to get a match because the addresses in my spreadsheet are not written exactly the same. My spreadsheet address may be 
24 ROCHDALE ROAD, Halifax, HX4 8AL

so i need to search by the term '24'

Comment: @Sureshmani. I'm adding the html to the original post now

Comment: I don't see the html, not sure if you think you added it. Also, did you look at the linked question above? That looked like what I would do

Answer (score 0):

Instead of iterating the list of [options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option) of the [select](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp) you could consider locating it directly using XPath [contains()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/contains) operator

```
value = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//option[contains(text(),'24')]").get_attribute("value")
housenumElem.select_by_value(value)
```

More information: [XPath Operators & Functions](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=40044727)