# I can't click on an option within a drop down field after selecting it using Selenium Webdriver with C# and Nunit

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, nunit

I am trying to select and click an option within a dropdown using C# code with Selenium Webdriver and Nunit Framework. I wrote the following code:

```
 IWebElement dropdown = Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='lane_id']"));
 new SelectElement(dropdown).SelectByText("All Lanes");
 dropdown.Click();
```

Now I know that dropdown.click() is wrong as it does not have the XPath for the selected option. But I want to somehow click the selected option.

P.S: Apologies for any mistake / community violations, this is my first ever query on stackoverflow.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selenium Select - Selecting dropdown option by part of the text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29772075/selenium-select-selecting-dropdown-option-by-part-of-the-text)

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: `Select` automatically choose the option for you. You don't need to click on option.