# how to select by a partial text in Python - selenium

Tags: python, selenium, drop-down-menu, automation

How can I select a dropdown element by a part of its name?
I want to select an option based on a DB values, but this values don't have the complete name of the dropdown element, is there any way to make selenium look for the option with my database value as a partial text?

```
    modelo = googleSheet.modelo.upper().strip()
    select = Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div/div/div/div[1]/form/fieldset[6]/div/ul/fieldset[3]/div/ul/fieldset[3]/div/ul/fieldset/div/ul/li/label'))))
    select.select_by_visible_text(modelo)
```

I the dropdown option I want to select is "Terrano II 2.7 xpto ol", but my data base value is just Terrano II 2.7

Thanks for the help

Comment: First thing is select only works with the Select tag. Next is you can use "//[contains(.,'{}')]".format("Terrano ll")  to select options with that value. Or starts-with

Comment: This is correct. 'Select' will work only with only with 'select' tag and 'option' tag as options in dropdown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`driver.select_by_visible_text()` already does `strip()`. You do not need it.
Also, from this method definition:

```
Select all options that display text matching the argument. That is, when given "Bar" this would select an option like:
<option value="foo">Bar</option>
:Args:
 - text - The visible text to match against
```

So, you need to expect exactly the option that is visible.
Another problem in your code is the way you pass the variable.

```
dropdown_option = "Some text you expect to see in the dropdown"
locator = driver.find_element_by_id("id")  # or any other locator
select = Select(locator)
        if locator is not None:
            for option in select.options:
                select.select_by_visible_text(dropdown_option)
```

This implementation makes debugging easier. For example you can print all the values from your dropdown before selecting the option you need.

If it takes a lot of time to dropdown to open, or other elements make your dropdown temporarily not visible, add a separate wait before selection.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

 wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
        wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(
            (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "Unique css selector of the first option in dropdown")))
```

Answer (score 0):

What about if first you extract the dropdown text content and then you check if your db query is in text? something like this:

[Selenium Select - Selecting dropdown option by part of the text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29772075/selenium-select-selecting-dropdown-option-by-part-of-the-text)

Comment: I didn't downvote you. I am just trying to make the code work cause it's python and the solution is not, but thanks for the answer. I think it is going somewhere :)

Comment: yes I know it is not python but most of the selenium command are the same (or almost). Therefore, I thought you could start from there..