# Extract full XML tree out of part of ID

Tags: c#, xml

Should be easy, but i have no idea how to do it:

I have id number like this:

```
ID1000
```

and i want to get this:

```
                <xf:instance id="etykiety_ID1000" xmlns="">
                    <sek>
                        <etykiety_ref>
                            <opt>
                                <item>dokument wymagany</item>
                                <value>1</value>
                            </opt>
                            <opt>
                                <item>dokument niewymagany</item>
                                <value>2</value>
                            </opt>
                            <opt>
                                <item>potwierdzenie sprawdzenia</item>
                                <value>3</value>
                            </opt>
                        </etykiety_ref>
                    </sek>
                </xf:instance>
```

this also:

```
<xf:bind id="ID1000"
    nodeset="wnio:TrescDokumentu/wnio:Wartosc/wnio:ID1000" relevant="true()"/>
```

but **not** this:

```
                <xf:instance id="etykiety_ID56" xmlns="">
                    <sek>
                        <etykiety_ref>
                            <opt>
                                <item>dokument wymagany</item>
                                <value>1</value>
                            </opt>
                            <opt>
                                <item>dokument niewymagany</item>
                                <value>2</value>
                            </opt>
                            <opt>
                                <item>potwierdzenie sprawdzenia</item>
                                <value>3</value>
                            </opt>
                        </etykiety_ref>
                    </sek>
                </xf:instance>
```

Other words, i want to get all ID1000 occurences with all artibutes and stuff inside.

Sorry if my question is basic knowledge, I'm begginer.

Comment: with XPath (2.0)? "//*[@id[ends-wth(.,'ID1000')]]"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22436789/xpath-ends-with-does-not-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use XML Linq

```css
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            var results = doc.Root.Elements()
                .Where(x => x.Attribute("id").Value.EndsWith("ID1000"));
        }
    }
}​
```