# how to locate dynamic element using xpath(ends-with function not working)

Tags: selenium, xpath

I have used ends-with function as 
(By.xpath("//input[ends-with(@id,'_PHONE$']"));

But it didnot work

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/36053559/edit) your question and add the HTML snippet of the element you are targetting.

Comment: hTML code is:<input maxlength="24" name="PERSONAL_PHONE_PHONE$1" id="PERSONAL_PHONE_PHONE$1" data-if-cloned-from="phoneEditRow" class="form-control" data-if-label="phoneEditRowNumber" data-if-source="input[id^=PERSONAL_PHONE_PHONE]" data-if-container-label="phoneEditRow" data-if-content="id name value maxlength" type="text">

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xpath "ends-with" does not work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22436789/xpath-ends-with-does-not-work)

Comment: used Mozilla firefox

Comment: Okay. Firefox supports XPath1.0 and `ends-with` function is part of 2.0. Do have a look at my answer or the [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22437888/2932244) for the solution.

Answer (score 11):

The `ends-with` function is part of XPath 2.0 but browsers generally only support 1.0.

So, if you strictly want to fetch all elements that ends with a specific pattern, you can either fetch all elements that contain that pattern (using the [`contains()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/contains) function) and then strictly check the suffix of the `id` (fetch the attribute value by [`.getAttribute("id")`](https://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#getAttribute(java.lang.String))) using Java's [`.endsWith()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#endsWith(java.lang.String)) method.

Or

You can use `string-length` function, `substring` function and equals to get this XPath:

```
"//input[substring(@id, string-length(@id) - string-length('_PHONE$1') +1) = '_PHONE$1']"
```

Comment: It works on my case! Thanks. I guess there is no "easier" selector, isn´t it? (it looks way complex)

Answer (score 0):

Your id is ending with _PHONE$1 and not _PHONE$. Notice that there is a `1` at the end.

```
(By.xpath("//input[ends-with(@id,'_PHONE$1']"));
```

If you still don't want to match that 1 use `contains`.

```
By.xpath("//input[contains(@id,'_PHONE$1']"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//id[contains(text(),'PHONE$')]"));
```

Comment: Sorry to say that it doesnt work for me.Is there any other solution

Answer (score 0):

You can use below XPath as well:-

```
//input[contains(@id,'PHONE$1')]
```

Hope it will help you :)

Answer (score -1):

Use contains Method

```
By.xpath("//input[contains(text(), '_PHONE$']");
```

**Or use wait explicit method**