# I need a regular Expression for Starts with and ends with

Tags: regex

I am looking for a regular expression for locating numerous expressions to find and replace. The expression looks like s360a__fieldname__c. I need to find all the instances where the s360a__ is then followed by the __c.

The issue is that it has to be within the one line so it is not finding a starting s360a__ and then the next __c which may be several lines below.

Here is an example of some of the xml I am changing.

```
<fields>
    <fullName>s360a__AddressPreferredStreetAddressCity__c</fullName>
    <deprecated>false</deprecated>
    <externalId>false</externalId>
    <label>Preferred Street City</label>
    <length>255</length>
    <required>false</required>
    <trackFeedHistory>false</trackFeedHistory>
    <trackHistory>false</trackHistory>
    <type>Text</type>
    <unique>false</unique>
</fields>
<fields>
    <fullName>s360a__AddressPreferredStreetAddressCountry__c</fullName>
    <deprecated>false</deprecated>
    <externalId>false</externalId>
    <label>Preferred Street Country</label>
    <picklist>
```

Comment: What environment are you using the regex in?

Answer (score 0):

You'd better of using a parser, combined with an `xpath` instead. Here's an example with `PHP` (can easily be adopted for e.g. `Python` as well). The idea is to load the `DOM`, then use a function to filter out elements (`starts-with()` and `text()` in this example):

```
<?php
$xml = '<fields>
    <fullName>s360a__AddressPreferredStreetAddressCity__c</fullName>
    <deprecated>false</deprecated>
    <externalId>false</externalId>
    <label>Preferred Street City</label>
    <length>255</length>
    <required>false</required>
    <trackFeedHistory>false</trackFeedHistory>
    <trackHistory>false</trackHistory>
    <type>Text</type>
    <unique>false</unique>
</fields>';

$dom = simplexml_load_string($xml);
// find everything where the text starts with 's360a_'
$fields = $dom->xpath("//*[starts-with(text(), 's360a_')]");
print_r($fields);
# s360a__AddressPreferredStreetAddressCity__c
```

The code checks if the text starts with `s360a_`. To actually check if it also *ends* with some specific string, you need to [fiddle quite a bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22436789/xpath-ends-with-does-not-work) (as the corresponding function `ends-with()` is not yet supported).

```
# check if the node text starts and ends with a specific string     
$fields = $dom->xpath("//*[starts-with(., 's360a_') and substring(text(), string-length(text()) - string-length('_c') +1) = '_c']");
?>
```