# Finding elements with selenium using Starts with and ends functions in xpath

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I am trying to extract all those tags whose class name fits the regex pattern frag-0-0, frag-1-0, etc. from this [enter link description here](http://de.vroniplag.wikia.com/wiki/Aak/002)

I am trying the following code

```
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
    for frg in frgs:
        driver.get(URL + frg[1:])
        frags=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[starts-with(@id, 'frag-') and ends-with(@id, '-0')]")
    for frag in frags:
            for tag in frag.find_elements_by_css_selector('[class^=fragmark]'):
                lst.append([tag.get_attribute('class'), tag.text])
    driver.quit()
```

This is my traceback:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/vroniplag/vroni.py", line 116, in 
>           op('Aaf')
>         File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/vroniplag/vroni.py", line 101, in op
>           plags=getplags(cd)
>         File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/vroniplag/vroni.py", line 92, in getplags
>           frags=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[starts-with(@id, 'frag-') and ends-with(@id, '-0')]")
>         File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py",
>   line 305, in find_elements_by_xpath
>           return self.find_elements(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
>         File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py",
>   line 778, in find_elements
>           'value': value})['value']
>         File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py",
>   line 236, in execute
>           self.error_handler.check_response(response)
>         File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py",
>   line 192, in check_response
>           raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
>       selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: Error Message => 'Unable to locate an element with the xpath
>   expression //*[starts-with(@id, 'frag-') and ends-with(@id, '-0')]
>   because of the following error:
>       Error: INVALID_EXPRESSION_ERR: DOM XPath Exception 51'
>        caused by Request => {"headers":{"Accept":"application/json","Accept-Encoding":"identity","Connection":"close","Content-Length":"139","Content-Type":"application/json;charset=UTF-8","Host":"127.0.0.1:45340","User-Agent":"Python-urllib/2.7"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"POST","post":"{\"using\":
>   \"xpath\", \"sessionId\": \"0dbc6ad0-4352-11e6-8cb8-4faebd646180\",
>   \"value\": \"//*[starts-with(@id, 'frag-') and ends-with(@id,
>   '-0')]\"}","url":"/elements","urlParsed":{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"elements","directory":"/","path":"/elements","relative":"/elements","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"","userInfo":"","authority":"","protocol":"","source":"/elements","queryKey":{},"chunks":["elements"]},"urlOriginal":"/session/0dbc6ad0-4352-11e6-8cb8-4faebd646180/elements"}
>       Screenshot: available via screen

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If your library does not support  Xpath 2.0 see there - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22436789/xpath-ends-with-does-not-work

Comment: Thanks. How do I know which version of XPath is installed? I am using ubuntu

Comment: I know nothing about python :(

Comment: Selenium only supports XPath 1.0 ...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can try to replace

```
"//*[starts-with(@id, 'frag-') and ends-with(@id, '-0')]"
```

with

```
"//*[starts-with(@id, 'frag-') and contains(@id, '-0')]"
```

as `Selenium` doesn't support `ends-with` option

Comment: Thanks. When I use it I am getting the following tags 
`frag-0
frag-0-b
frag-0-0
frag-0-1
frag-0
frag-0-b
frag-0-0`

Comment: it should end with -0

Comment: The following worked for me `"//*[starts-with(@id, 'frag-') and substring(@id, 7)='-0']"`

Comment: yeah. Good solution