# Unable to locate input box with ends-with keyword- Xpath

Tags: html, css, xpath, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

Thank you for taking a look. I've been able to work out with `starts-with` for below source code but for some reason, the `ends-with` doesn't work

`<input type="text" value="" name="email" style="background-color: rgb(248, 248, 248);"/>`

`//input[starts-with(@name,'ema')]`- Works absoultelty fine

`css=input[name*='ema']`- Works fine

`css=input[name$='ail']` - Works fine

`//input[ends-with(@name,'ail')]`- doesn't work

`//input[ends-with(@.,'ail')]`- doesn't work

I am using firepath 0.9.7.1.1 & also tried in version 1.0- no luck. Thanks in advance
I've already tried [Xpath "ends-with" does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22436789/xpath-ends-with-does-not-work) & it didn't help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xpath "ends-with" does not work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22436789/xpath-ends-with-does-not-work)

Comment: Please don't tell us that something "doesn't work". Tell us how it fails.

Comment: so whats the error you getting.  Are you sure your input has name which is ending exactly with 'ail' ? check if there is space after 'ail'

Answer (score 1):

The ends-with() function requires XPath 2.0.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I've tried this with xpath 2.0 & it doesn't work. Of my surpise, the `starts-with` function work but not `ends-with` 

@har07 I've already tried that approach prior posting this query.

Comment: Don't tell us it doesn't work, tell us exactly what you did and exactly how it fails. There are two possibilities: your XPath engine is not a (conformant) XPath 2.0 engine, or you called ends-with() incorrectly. If you told us how it failed, we would probably be able to eliminate one of these possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

Firepath only supports XPath 1.0. From FirePath description on [Mozilla Add-ons](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firepath/) page :

> FirePath is a Firebug extension that adds a development tool to ***edit, inspect and generate XPath 1.0 expressions***, CSS 3 selectors and JQuery selectors (Sizzle selector engine).

So you can not use `ends-with()` function with FirePath. As explained in the linked question, you need to resort to manual implementation of `ends-with()` function logic using XPath 1.0 supported functions i.e `substring()` and `string-length()` :

```
//input[substring(@name, string-length(@name) - string-length('ema') +1) = 'ema']
```