# Xpath get a if href contains part of string

Tags: html, dom, xpath, css-selectors

Hi there I tried to get all elements which contain href=/p/{random}/?tagged=see
Here is my line

```
//div[preceding::h2[text()='Most recent']]/div/div/a[@href='/p/*/?tagged=see']
```

How I can fix this code, I must replace the '*' with something else?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In XPath 2.0 or above, you can use Regex functions, for example :

```
//a[matches(@href, '/p/.*/\?tagged=see')]
```

Or using combination of string functions `starts-with()` and `ends-with()` :

```
//a[starts-with(@href, '/p/')]
   [ends-with(@href, '/?tagged=see')]
```

XPath 1.0 doesn't have regex nor `ends-with()` functions, however, you can [simulate the latter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22437888/2998271) :

```
//a[starts-with(@href, '/p/')]
   [substring(@href, string-length(@href) - string-length('/?tagged=see') +1) = '/?tagged=see']
```

Simplified :

```
//a[starts-with(@href, '/p/')]
   [substring(@href, string-length(@href) - 11) = '/?tagged=see']
```