# Why can I do a "contains" call on the class attribute of an element but not other attributes like href with XPath?

Tags: c#, html, .net, xpath, html-agility-pack

I just started looking into XPath but am a little confused on the following.

I'm parsing HTML (using the HTML-Agility-Pack in C# / .NET) and I'm able to call the contains function on the "class" attribute for an HTML element to only select the nodes whose class contains a specific value.

For example, the top answer on this SO: [How can I match on an attribute that contains a certain string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1390568/how-can-i-match-on-an-attribute-that-contains-a-certain-string)

But I'm unable to call the contains function on the "href" attribute of the HTML "a" (hyperlink) element.

For example, it seems like a more complicate solution is needed, as per this SO accepted answer: [Xpath get a if href contains part of string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42901078/xpath-get-a-if-href-contains-part-of-string)

And if I try to use the following XPath code, I get the ArgumentNullException: "Value cannot be null" exception.

```
//td/a[contains(@href, 'part-of-the-hyperlink')]
```

This is the relevant part of HTML I'm trying to select:

```html
<td>
<a href="/name/part-of-the-hyperlink">
Hugh Dane
</a>          
</td>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I'm surprised at the exception. The conformant behaviour when you supply an empty node-set as the first argument of contains() is to return false. You should of course be supplying `@href` rather than `href`.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I was actually using @href. That was just a typo I now fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
//td/a[contains(href, 'part-of-the-hyperlink')]
```

to

```
//td/a[contains(@href, 'part-of-the-hyperlink')]
```

to test the ***attribute***, `href`, otherwise you're testing the `href` *child element* (which doesn't exist).

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. That was a typo in my question text. I actually was using @href already and still receive the error I stated in my question.