# XPath matching wildcards?

Tags: xml, xpath

Looking to use a wildcard in an xpath where the attribute is a path and I want all paths that end with "text".

**Example**:  `<Property name="jcr:content/MainParsys/*/text"/>`

- `jcr:content/MainParsys`  is constant.
- `*` is where I want the wildcard (all paths in-between).
- `text` is the last part of the path I am looking for.

In addition, there are paths that end in `/textIsRich` that I want to avoid.

**Look for:** `<Property name="jcr:content/MainParsys/*/text"/>`

**Avoid:**  `<Property name="jcr:content/MainParsys/*/text *"/>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### XPath 1.0

This XPath,

```
//Property[@name[  starts-with(.,'jcr:content/MainParsys/')
         and substring(., string-length(.) - string-length('/text') +1) = '/text']]
```

will select all `Property` elements with an `name` attribute whose value starts with `'jcr:content/MainParsys/'` and ends with `'/text'` (using the standard [XPath 1.0 work-around for no `ends-with()` function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22437888/290085)).

### XPath 2.0

XPath 2.0 has `ends-with()` and also regex functions such as [`matches()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-matches) that can match effective wildcards (`.*`), for example.

Comment: @matt: Oops, you're right of course.  Answer corrected.  Thanks.