# XML XPATH ATTRIBUTE

Tags: xml, xpath

Can anyone help me to get the Z NAMES data with only one xpath syntax?

```
<fields>
 <field name="Z01NAME">Romulo</field>
 <field name="Z02NAME">Marco</field>
 <field name="Z03NAME">Tan</field>
 <field name="X01NAME">Joseph</field>
 <field name="X02NAME">EXB</field>
</fields>
```

I tried `/fields/field[@name="Z*NAME"]` but it doesn't work. Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *XPath 1.0* does not support wilcards or regular expressions. You could solve the question using `starts-with()`, function. To implement `ends-with()` function  use @IanRoberts' [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22437888/7914637). So, the final expression is

```
/fields/field[starts-with(@name,'Z') and substring(@name, string-length(@name) - string-length('NAME') +1) = 'NAME']
```

Comment: the 'ends-with' function is not working,  but starts-with partially answers my question and is a big help already. Thank you!.

Comment: @RomzMarco, you are right! The `ends-with()` implementation is proposed in the [Xpath “ends-with” does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22436789/7914637) topic.