# Xpath ends-with() function - Not finding a match

Tags: xpath

Very new with xpath and trying to learn how to use it.

I have a xpath in chrome browser that changes except for the last 2 or 3 characters.

I was told about the ends-with() function. However, I seem to be doing something wrong. Because it is not finding the id element.

I am using Auto-It with web-driver if that maters. This is what I have tried.

```
$sElement = _WD_FindElement($sSession, $_WD_LOCATOR_ByXPath, '//*[ends-with(@id,"_4")]')  ;;enters dob
```

Tried these as well.

```
$sElement = _WD_FindElement($sSession, $_WD_LOCATOR_ByXPath, "//*substring(@id, string-length(@id) - string-length('_4') +1) = '_4'")  



$sElement = _WD_FindElement($sSession, $_WD_LOCATOR_ByXPath, "//*[substring(@id, string-length(@id) - string-length('_4') + 1 ) = '_4']")



$sElement = _WD_FindElement($sSession, $_WD_LOCATOR_ByXPath, "//*[@id[substring(., string-length(.) - string-length('_4') + 1 ) = '_4']]")
```

I know the first part of my code is okay because these lines do work.

```
$sElement = _WD_FindElement($sSession, $_WD_LOCATOR_ByXPath, '//*[@id="sysmenu-searchbarinput"]')

$sElement = _WD_FindElement($sSession, $_WD_LOCATOR_ByXPath, '//*[@id="sysmenu-searchbarbutton"]')
```

Here is what my normal xpath would be if it was not dynamic.

```
//*[@id="in972_4"]
```

[image]

```
<input id="in8nM_4" type="text" spellcheck="false" style="box-sizing:border-box;width:100%;vertical-align:top;color:inherit;" name="in8nM_14" class="navitem s_92" data-evt="Fi Fo" data-evh-fi="Pweb.input.inputTextFocusInWrapper" data-evh-fo="Pweb.input.inputTextFocusOutWrapper" data-evt-props="[&quot;altStyle&quot;]" data-befieldchanged-url="./0000000000016jz9v3.mthd" aria-labelledby="y8nM_1u">
```

Comment: Browsers are using XPath 1.0 and ends-with() function is not part of XPath 1.0. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22436789/xpath-ends-with-does-not-work

Comment: am I do something wrong here? $sElement = _WD_FindElement($sSession, $_WD_LOCATOR_ByXPath, "//*substring(@id, string-length(@id) - string-length('_4') +1) = '_4'")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are trying to do, this XPath could work:

```
//*[substring(@id, string-length(@id) - string-length('_4') + 1 ) = '_4']
```

Even better to put the predicate on the @id because you are using it multiple times. Like this:

```
//*[@id[substring(., string-length(.) - string-length('_4') + 1 ) = '_4']]
```

Comment: I really appreciate the help! I edited my question with more info. I tried both examples with no luck unfortunately. I am over here pulling my hair out. haha

Comment: Could you share the actual url, in stead of the picture ?

Comment: I was afraid you were going to ask that. No, it is a work site behind a login.

Comment: Copy a relevant part of the live html to the question then. So not source, but what you see with inspect code.

Comment: at the bottom of my question. (in black) That's what you mean right?

Comment: Not really. I saw that.  And the XPath should work based on that picture. But to experiment a bit more it is always the best to share the actual html-chars in stead of a picture.

Comment: Oh crap sorry, I added to the post.

Comment: Both XPath's should work. Something else is wrong. Sorry.

Comment: Don't be sorry!

Comment: I figured out your code does work! However, It just doesn't work on the pop up that the browser brings up. If I enter the stuff in the pop up window manually and then get back to the original page the code works perfectly on other elements. Any idea why it wouldn't work in the pop up? Hopefully, that makes sense...

Comment: Looks like it is in a "dynamic" I frame.  I got bigger problems it seems.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232970/discussion-between-siebe-jongebloed-and-skyslastchance).